# PHP version different on server then the one set in vhost

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, php, hosts-file

So I have an odd problem.

I followed this tutorial

https://tecadmin.net/install-multiple-php-version-apache-ubuntu/

to install multiple versions of PHP on my local server. On most sites it works, but on one of my sites when I do a phpinfo I get the info about the newest version of php I have installed on my machine instead of the one specified in my v-host file.

What else could be happening to change the version of php?

This is my v-host file

```
ServerName something.local.si

DocumentRoot /var/www/something/public_html

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/something/error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/something/access.log combined

<Directory /var/www/something/public_html>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

The version that runs in Apache is solely configured by this directive in `httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule php5_module    /path/to/php/and/the/module/for/apache2/libphp5.so
```

This is the directive you need to modify to use the specific version you want
running. The `phpinfo` utility should give this same running version.